# How to play HTML5 <video> in landscape mode for phonegap android application

Tags: android, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

In my phonegap android application i have used  tag of HTML5 to play video.
My whole application is in portrait mode. But i want to play video in landscape mode.

I have used below code:

```
<video controls="" id="video_player_control"><source src="http://192.254.5.6/somevideo/Inception.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

This is working for iOS phonegap application i.e. video is playing in landscape mode for iOS. But on android video doesn't rotate.

Any kind of help appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

try like this

add this config.xml value:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
```

then set orientation to landscape

```
video.addEventListener('playing', function() {
     var so = cordova.plugins.screenorientation;
     so.setOrientation(so.Orientation.LANDSCAPE);
}, false);
```

refer this link [landscape](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/5/24/PhoneGap-Tip-Temporarily-changing-orientation-for-video-in-a-portrait-only-application)

Comment: not working.. i have already added <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/> in config.xml file.

Comment: video.addEventListener is executing

Comment: i have added alert in the "addEventListener" function to see whether this is function is invoking or not. but this function is not invoking.

Comment: call this when you clicked action to play the video

Comment: i am not using plugin for playing video.. so how should i call this cordova.plugins.screenorientation. I am just giving src to <video> tag..like below:  <video controls="" id="video_player_control"><source src="http://192.254.5.6/somevideo/Inception.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

Answer (score 0):

Try this . its working for me

```
cordova.require('cordova/plugin/screenorientation').set("landscape");
```

Check this may help https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video

Comment: hi. where to add above line.

Comment: i have not using plugin to play video. i am using simple HTML5 video tag fro that. So there is no file like ScreenOrientaion.java in my project.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<video id="video1"><source src="url" type="video/mp4" /></video>
```

CSS

```
 video#video1 {
position:fixed;
margin-top:32%;
margin-left:-39%;
-moz-transform:scale(1) rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform:scale(1) rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform:scale(1) rotate(90deg);
  transform:scale(1) rotate(90deg); }
```